# How can I set a property for AutoMouseScroll and Mouse hower property to UltraDropdown?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I am using UltraDropDown control to bind a column of one UltraGrid control to list People category in list format.

This drop-down control have more than 25 items and show 8 categories Max, it's very fine. Now whenever I click on drop-down control to see all people category list then i have to hold scroll bar and drag down to see all categories. but I want to show all categories when I mouse scroll and its automatically move up and down to show all, and one more thing I want, when i mouse hover on listed categories then hover item should be shaded or colored.

Please help on both topic.

Thanks & Regards,
Shashi Bhushan Jaiswal[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first requirement is by default as behavior. Are you handling the MouseWheel event for this to not work?

Here is the code for your second requirement but I do not know if it is a good approach to use the MouseHover event as you like but this is your requirement:

```
    void ultraDropDown1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cell != null && isInItem) {cell.Cell.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;}
    }

    CellUIElement cell;
    bool isInItem = false;
    private void ultraDropDown1_MouseEnterElement(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UIElementEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Element is EditorWithTextDisplayTextUIElement && e.Element.Parent.Parent is CellUIElement)
        {
            cell = (CellUIElement)e.Element.Parent.Parent;
            isInItem = true;
        }
        else isInItem = false;
    }
```